# Magnet falling through a copper tube

Tags: electromagnetism

I am doing an experiment, on a magnet falling through a copper tube.

I am investigating, how the does variation of height from which a magnet is dropped through a copper tube, affect the horizontal distance it travels.

I did a demo for 10cm and 20cm, where I released a sphere magnet first at a height of 10cm through a copper tube and released a sphere magnet at a height of 20cm through a copper. tube.

I know that a magnet in general takes a longer time to travel through a copper tube.

When I tested for these two heights, I noticed that at 20cm the magnet takes a shorter time to come out from the copper tube compared to when the magnet is released 10cm and also it has a longer horizontal distance travelled when it's dropped at 20cm compared to the 10cm?

I wanted to ask the Physics and reasoning behind this. Is the KE larger in magnitude to the breaking force when dropped at higher heights? Can someone explain the reasoning the Physics for the observations and data collected? Thanks.

Comment: I bent the copper tube a bit it is not a straight copper tube.

Comment: Is it a curve or is it a sharp turning point (as in a non-differentiable point)? I think a brief diagram of the setup would help.

Comment: Presumably your tube is shaped like a J i.e. a vertical section that has curve to horizontal at the bottom. Can you draw a diagram showing the shape and dimensions of the tube?